# Allow permission dialog in Flutter end-to-end testing in IOS?

Tags: flutter, testing

I am using IOS for testing in flutter. When permission dialog appears, how can I grant permission inside testing?

Comment: you can do it with `xcrun simctl` I think.

`xcrun simctl privacy <device-ID> grant all <bundle-id>` will grant all permission. 
Then you can start running your tests..

To know what all permission it granted, execute `xcrun simctl privacy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12561), I found another solution:

For Andriod:

```
adb shell pm grant <appId> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

flutter drive \
  --driver=integration_test/driver.dart \
  --target=integration_test/location_test.dart \
  -d <deviceId>
```

For IOS:

```
brew tap wix/brew
brew install applesimutils
applesimutils --byId <deviceId> --bundle <appId> --setPermissions location=always

flutter drive \
 --driver=integration_test/driver.dart \
 --target=integration_test/location_test.dart \
 -d <deviceId>
```

Comment: doesn't work for iOS if you use real device (because you need bluetooth) :(